# my iPhone software is so slow!

Tags: iphone, testing, performance

I ported one of my mac applications to the iphone.  WOW!!! is it slow!  At first I started thinking maybe I was doing a lot of disk access.  But as I started looking I realized I simply do an offset read of a binary file.  I only read in about 512 bytes of data.  I also have an array that is huge.  Maybe 2MB.  But why would that be slow?  It is perminatly located in memory.

I would love to hear some ideas from you all!

Comment: This should be a www.superuser.com question. Please migrate this.

Comment: The OP is referring to the performance of his own software; that's appropriate for SO, not SU.

Answer (score 2):

When you have major performance problems, the tool to pull out first is [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). Start with "Run With Performance Tool > CPU Sampler" and get a feel for where your app is spending its time. After that, check Object Allocations to see if you're hitting memory harder than you should. iPhone is a resource-constrained environment compared to the Mac. Things that you think of as fast can dramatically impact performance on iPhone. Disk access is much more expensive. Even allocating memory can be a significant impact (welcome to the world that server developers deal with every day). You only have one core, so things you stuck off on a background thread now compete with your main thread. It's a different world.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to debug the application over Stackoverflow, but there are many reasons why the iPhone app runs much slower:  Your mac applications run on probably the latest CPUs with tons of memory, as for the iPhone it's very limited (3GS is rumored to have 600MHz CPU with 256MB RAM).  Also, Mac applications are a bit more forgiving when it comes to memory usage; as for the iPhone it's important that only create the objects you need when you need them and release them when you no longer use them.  Delaying object de-allocation results in some slowdown as well.

I recommend using Instruments performance profiling tool, that is bundled with XCode and the Developer tools.  It'll give good tips on what the bottlenecks are.